# Implement Sylius into Symfony2 Standard Edition

Tags: symfony, sylius

Hoi,

I am trying to implement the Sylius e-commerce bundles into a fresh Symfony 2.2.2 Standard Edition.

When running the sylius:install command from commandline, i keep getting the following error:

```
The class 'Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartItemInterface' was not found in
the chain configured namespaces Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity,
Sylius\Bundle\SettingsBundle\Entity, Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Entity,
Sylius\Bundle\AssortmentBundle\Entity, Sylius\Bundle\TaxationBundle\Entity,
Sylius\Bundle\ShippingBundle\Entity, Sylius\Bundle\PaymentsBundle\Entity,
Sylius\Bundle\PromotionsBundle\Entity, Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Entity,
Sylius\Bundle\SalesBundle\Entity, Sylius\Bundle\InventoryBundle\Entity,
Sylius\Bundle\TaxonomiesBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Entity
```

The Bundles are imported via `Composer`, activated via `AppKernel.php`, I've migrated the dependencies and configuration from a plain `Sylius` installation and actually have no idea, where this error comes from. I just noticed, that its trying to find a Model inside an Entiy-Namespace, which can't be right.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem, we are working with symfony 2.1. I fixed it by reordering the bundles registration in the app Kernel.php file.

In this file I placed the syliusCart bundle register before all the other sylius bundles and the doctrine registers.

I really dont know what is causing this or why this worked for me... but I hope this works for you.

Cheers!

Comment: Jap, that really solves the problem. I just realized, they also placed the Sylius-Bundles before the Doctrine-Bundles in the Sylius application. Thanks for helping me out! I'll report it to the dev-team.